# Cannot install big size APK

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-install-apk, apk-expansion-files

I have created android application that have big size in assets. More than 200 MB when I exported to the APK. When I installed to my Cyrus tablet always failed to install. 
The APK has been successfully installed on my Galaxy Note II, but the log in eclipse the installation failed and Google Play services crashes.
I know that if upload the APK to the Google store no more than 50 MB. But I won't upload to the store, only for myself.
Sometimes when I installed the apk (more than 200 MB) is successfully installed. But now, always failed. I don't know why. Its weird. I have tried to clear data Google Play Store and Google Play Services but still failed to install an apk. And than I disable them, but still failed.
Is there any way that could install big size apk?

Comment: Did you consider to use an expansion file?

Comment: Please contact the manufacturer of your device and ask them about the problem.

Comment: @Henry yes, if i uploaded to the store. But if don't, I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare is the problem from the device? I was thinking the problem from my Manifest file. I set android:installLocation="auto" . I don't know it will fix my problem.

Comment: "is the problem from the device?" -- you are the one saying that it fails to install on a Cyrus tablet but installs successfully on a Galaxy Note II. You have not explained the nature of "failed to install" (e.g., what error you got when running **`adb install`**). Hence, AFAIK, the problem is with the Cyrus tablet. All that being said, I would not recommend a 200MB APK file, even for non-Play Store use. Bear in mind that installation requires at least twice the space, and so if your Cyrus does not have at least 400MB free space on internal storage, the install will fail.